# VSCode Clang-Tidy squiggling <iostream> header because "__float128 is not supported on this target"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang-tidy

As seen in [this video](https://i.imgur.com/atgwLW2.mp4), the C++ Linter provided in the C/C++ extension from Microsoft (clang-tidy) in VSCode squiggles the  header of the standard library, producing an irresolvable problem.

However, outside of this fact, the linter works as expected, as demonstrated by the double-declaration being squiggled and clearing itself after being removed in the video.

I have tried many solutions to this problem:

Using `// NOLINT` (and its derivates such as `//NOLINTNEXTLINE`) as described in the [clang-tidy documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/). This does not change anything.

```cpp
#include <iostream> // NOLINT
```

Using the `--header_filter=` argument, in the following forms, which completely broke the linting:

```json
"C_Cpp.codeAnalysis.clangTidy.headerFilter": "^((?!std_abs\\.h|stl_algobase\\.h|type_traits).)*$",
```

```json
"C_Cpp.codeAnalysis.clangTidy.args": [
    "--header_filter='^((?!std_abs\\.h|stl_algobase\\.h|type_traits).)*$'"
],
```

This does not work as Posix ERE does not support negative lookahead and the header filter is supposed to specify which ones to check, not which ones to ignore.
I also tried matching the offending files, even though the documentation specifies the exact opposite, which also broke the linting.

Using `--line-filter` to filter the line out, which also broke the linting:

```json
"C_Cpp.codeAnalysis.clangTidy.args": [
        "--line-filter=[{\"name\":\"vscode_main.cpp\", \"lines\": [[1,1]]}]"
],
```

I also tried the opposite version of that, to no avail:

```json
"C_Cpp.codeAnalysis.clangTidy.args": [
        "--line-filter=[{\"name\":\"vscode_main.cpp\", \"lines\": [[2,1000]]}]"
],
```

In conclusion, my attempts either did nothing or broke linting completely. If anyone has any solutions to or suggestions regarding the problem and could post them, I'd be glad.

Comment: Does the code compile ?

Comment: @RichardCritten, yes, it's clang-tidy complaining for no reason.